# R - Regex to remove foreign unicode characters

Tags: r, regex, unicode

I want to use R to perform some analytics on Twitter posts, such as this Tweet by Donald Trump (pulled via the Twitter API):

```
"Join me LIVE in South Korea\U0001f1fa\U0001f1f8\U0001f1f0\U0001f1f7\n#NationalAssembly #POTUSinAsia"
```

First I would like to know if these is a regular expression that I can use to select the escaped unicode (e.g.: `\U0001f1f8`).

Expressions that I would assume would work, such as this: `\\[[:alnum:]]{9}` do not work. I got an interesting error message, however:

> Error in grepl("\[[:alnum:]]{9}", x, perl = T) :    invalid regular
>   expression '[[:alnum:]]{9}' In addition: Warning message: In
>   grepl("\[[:alnum:]]{9}", x, perl = T) : PCRE pattern compilation
>   error     'POSIX named classes are supported only within a class'     at
>   '[:alnum:]]{9}'

Also, I'd like to know if there is a way I can convert these escaped unicode back into the characters they are supposed to represent so I can display them to the user on the front-end of the application.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `iconv`. This will remove all Non-ASCII characters that includes your foreign Unicode characters.

```
teststring <- "Join me LIVE in South Korea\U0001f1fa\U0001f1f8\U0001f1f0\U0001f1f7\n#NationalAssembly #POTUSinAsia"

iconv(teststring, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")
#[1] "Join me LIVE in South Korea\n#NationalAssembly #POTUSinAsia"
```